# Java ArrayList type error/warning

Tags: java, arraylist, incompatibletypeerror, unchecked-conversion

While attempting to implement a custom data class I have run into the following problem. I'm simply trying to add items to an ArrayList but Java seems to have an issue with the types I'm using. I have tried multiple solutions to no avail. Below I have included the code from my custom datatype and from a simplified version of my code that throws the same errors. I have included the two solutions I tried and the error/warning each threw.

I am relatively new to code and especially to asking questions on StackOverflow so if I have forgotten anything or can clarify please let me know.

Custom Datatype:

```
  1 /**
  2 This file defines a transition function data type
  3 */
  4 
  5 import java.util.ArrayList;
  6 
  7 public class transition<X,Y,Z> {
  8         private ArrayList<Integer> current;
  9         private char scan;
 10         private ArrayList<Integer> future;
 11 
 12         //constructors
 13         public transition(int x, char y, int z) {
 14                 this.current = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 15                 this.current.add(x);
 16                 this.scan = y;
 17                 this.future = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 18                 this.future.add(z);
 19         }
 20 
 21         public transition(ArrayList<Integer> x, char y, ArrayList<Integer> z) {
 22                 this.current = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 23                 this.current = x;
 24                 this.scan = y;
 25                 this.future = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 26                 this.future = z;
 27         }
 28 
 29         //methods
 30         public ArrayList<Integer> getCurrent() {
 31                 return this.current;
 32         }
 33 
 34         public char getScan() {
 35                 return this.scan;
 36         }
 37 
 38         public ArrayList<Integer> getFuture() {
 39                 return this.future;
 40         }
 41 }
```

Simplified Code:

```
 1 /**
  2 Class designed to test out a bug encountered in my code
  3 */
  4 
  5 import java.util.ArrayList;
  6 
  7 public class test {
  8 
  9         public static void main(String[] args) {
 10 
 11                 //creating ArrayList and adding one transition to it
 12                 ArrayList<transition> list = new ArrayList<transition>();
 13                 transition trans = new transition(1, 'a', 2);
 14                 list.add(trans);
 15 
 16                 //creating list to add to
 17                 ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 18 
 19                 //testing loops over ArrayList and calls to trans
 20                 for(transition t : list) {
 21 
 22                         if(t.getCurrent().contains(1) && t.getScan() == 'a') {
 23 
 24                                                                         //Option 1
 25                                 ints.addAll(t.getFuture());             //t.java:24 warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
 26                                                                         //found    : java.util.ArrayList
 27                                                                         //required : java.util.Collection<? extends java.lang.Integer>
 28 
 29                                                                         //Option 2
 30                                 for(Integer j : t.getFuture()) {        //      t.java:26: incompatible types
 31                                         ints.add(j);                    //      found    : java.lang.Object
 32                                 }                                       //      required : java.lang.Integer
 33                         }
 34                 }
 35         }
 36 }
```

Comment: What error / warning message?? Please post the full unabridged message. And where -- what line of code is the offending code?? And please get rid of the line numbers -- they definitely won't help and **will** distract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `transition` is a generic class (it has 3 type parameters `<X, Y, Z>`).

Since `t` is a raw `transition` (as opposed to a `transition<String, Integer, Date>` for example), **all** of the generic type information in `transition` is completely ignored for the variable `t`. (Yes, that *really is* how raw types work).

So it's as if `getFuture` returns a mere `ArrayList`, rather than an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Just get rid of `<X, Y, Z>` (I see no reason why they're there anyway) and it should work.

A simple demonstration of this problem is this:

```
public class Main<T> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = new Main().getList().get(0);       // Doesn't compile
    }

    List<Integer> getList() { return Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3); }
}
```

This doesn't compile, but if you delete `<T>`, it does.

Comment: Spot on answer. Completely solved the issue. Thanks so much. o/

Comment: To further my understanding, if I replaced X, Y and Z with specific types such as ArrayList<Integer>, char and ArrayList<Integer> respectively then this will compile correctly because transition is no longer a generic type, correct?

Comment: Primitive types like `char` cannot be generic types. You have to use `Character` instead. It sounds like you want to use a generic interface. `public interface Transition<X, Y, Z>` with methods like `Y getScan();` etc. Then you would need a concrete implementation like `public MyTransition implements Transition<List<Integer>, Character, List<Integer>> { code is just like before }`. If you do this, `MyTransition` would not be generic, yes.